# Quadtree and kd-tree splitting and mandelbrot set?

Tags: kdtree, quadtree, mandelbrot

I've read about a quadtree or kd-tree splitting and a mandelbrot set but what when the rectangle before the first split and the frame lies in the mandelbrot set or has the same iteration depth and the algorithm returns from tiling? How can I force to skip filling a rectangle when it's too big?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: When you are looking at the root of the tree what happens when you start to subdivide the space?

Comment: reminds me of http://williamedwardscoder.tumblr.com/post/26628848007/rod-marching